# Written Program does have no ouput, nor wants input

Tags: python

I am currently trying to learn python and I want to understand how the whole class, function and overall hierarchical structure stuff works.

I am trying to make a simple program that asks for the input of the user and multiplies it, than prints it. But i want to nest it in some functions and classes.

Furthermore, I am not really sure about the parsed parameters.

Would highly appreciate any input :)

I just compleded reading similar threads i found in Google as well as various tutorials, but I can not get my head around it.

The dubugger just skips the content of these functions

```
class Rechnung(object):
    def __init__(self, summe):
        eingabenutzer(x, y, z)
        rechnung(x, y, z)
        print (summe)

    def eingabenutzer(self):
        x=input('enter x')
        y=input('enter y')
        z=input('enter z')
        return x,y,z;

    def rechnung(self, x, y, z):
        summe=x*y*z 
        return summe;
```

LF: Ask for input x,y,z -> print summe (sum)

Actual: None

Comment: You defined a class, how do you instantiate it?

Comment: You are not creating an object out of your class, nor calling its methods. I'd start with that.

Comment: Is that all your code? Because all you're doing is defining things, not making anything actually happen. Once you define your object, you have to instantiate it and then call its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working, just comment for unclear details, there where multible bugs.

```
class Rechnung(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x, y, z = self.eingabenutzer()
        summe = self.rechnung(x, y, z)
        print(summe)

    def eingabenutzer(self):
        x=int(input('enter x'))
        y=int(input('enter y'))
        z=int(input('enter z'))
        return x,y,z

    def rechnung(self, x, y, z):
        summe = x*y*z
        return summe;

Rechnung()  # <--- this call is creating your class and will run the __init__()
```